# Work around invalid byte sequences in a WCF response

Tags: c#, wcf

The WCF endpoint I retrieve data from has started returning responses which include invalid byte sequences. Unfortunately, this won't be fixed upstream until the next release cycle, so until then, I need to work around it; i.e. I need to modify my WCF client, so that it ignores the invalid byte sequences returned from the server, rather than crashing and burning.

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'getTerminationPointsIterator'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 14291602). ---> System.Xml.XmlException: The byte 0x13 is not valid at this location.  Line 1, position 14291602.
   at System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowXmlException(XmlDictionaryReader reader, String res, String arg1, String arg2, String arg3)
   at System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowInvalidXml(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Byte b)
   at System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadNode(Boolean skipOverWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.ReadCurrentNode(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.ReadNode(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ReadXmlNode(Boolean wrapped)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderTerminationPointRetrieval_RPC.Read21_AnyListType(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderTerminationPointRetrieval_RPC.Read64_PhysicalTerminationPointType(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderTerminationPointRetrieval_RPC.Read86_TerminationPointType(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderTerminationPointRetrieval_RPC.Read93_Item(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderTerminationPointRetrieval_RPC.Read248_Item()
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer122.Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader reader)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.XmlSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, XmlSerializer serializer, MessagePartDescription returnPart, MessagePartDescriptionCollection bodyParts, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
```

---

At first, I tried implementing `IClientMessageInspector#AfterReceiveReply`, to try and filter the invalid characters from the `Message`;

```
public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
{
    Message revised = null;
    var contents = new StringBuilder();
    var filtered = new StringBuilder();
    var writer = XmlWriter.Create(contents, new XmlWriterSettings
    {
        CheckCharacters = false
    });

    reply.WriteMessage(writer);
    writer.Flush();

    foreach (var c in contents.ToString())
    {
        if (XmlConvert.IsXmlChar(c))
        {
            filtered.Append(c);
        }
    }

    revised = Message.CreateMessage(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(filtered.ToString())), Int32.MaxValue, reply.Version);
    revised.Properties.CopyProperties(reply.Properties);
    reply = revised;
}
```

... but this throws at the `reply.WriteMessage(writer)` line with the same error:

> An exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Runtime.Serialization.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The byte 0x13 is not valid at this location.  Line 1, position 14291602.

Can anyone suggest a way for my client to gracefully parse the invalid response, filtering out the invalid XML characters?

Comment: I think you'll generally find that you cannot manipulate invalid XML data with any of the XML classes (deserialize, and so on) - they all expect the XML to be valid. However, WCF provides numerous hook points, and though I am a bit rusty (I haven't worked with WCF for a few years now) I am 99 percent sure there's a way to define a hook that will give you access to the raw input stream before serialization takes place - you should be able to tweak the incoming data there.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: Thanks for your help. I'm as sure as you that there is a hook *somewhere* that I can use; but I'm struggling to find exactly which hook to use! All the ones I've come across so far seem to be too late in the pipeline; i.e. the response is already in a `Message`, and I can only find ways to get XML out of `Message` objects, and not the raw contents.

Comment: I meant before DEserialization takes place, of course. I believe the class you want to look at is [MessageEncoder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.messageencoder(v=vs.110).aspx) - it is responsible for both encoding and decoding WCF messages, and you can modify the raw bytes from within a descendant.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I have the exact problem but using an Mtom message so wrapping around a custom MessageEncoder might not be the most ideal option.

Comment: In my case, the hooks are either too late (as above) or too early; I am using MTOM.